# Arguments for mount in Android recovery update script

Tags: android, adb, mount, edify

When looking at the update that was released for Android 4.2.2 (see [link](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_nakasi/6ece895ecb23.signed-nakasi-JDQ39-from-JOP40D.6ece895e.zip) ), I was trying to understand the scipt file they wrote.

It contains:

```
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/platform/sdhci-tegra.3/by-name/APP", "/system");
```

I am new to writing such script files. I know linux has a `mount` command. How do the four arguments above relate to linux `mount` command and what do they mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So android update zip file are typically written in edify script (may vary depending on what recovery image you have). Some sources for reading

http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/themes-apps/tutorial-making-flashable-zips-edify-t1611615

http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Edify_script_language

Answer (score 1):

`mount` parameters are:

1. FS type (any supported file system)
2. partition type (`EMMC` or `MTD`)
3. partition (block device) to mount
4. mount point